# why the drawSomething doesn't work

Tags: backbone.js

I use the backbone to test something, but i don't know why the drawSomething just no show @@"

```
initialize: function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        //alert("Hello");
        this.drawSomething();
    }, 1000);
},
drawSomething: function() {
    alert('hi');
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that inside `setInterval` callback context `this` is not what you expect (it's global object `window`). Simplest fix is to save proper object reference in variable:

```
var self = this;
setInterval(function() {
    //alert("Hello");
    self.drawSomething();
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

as you are using backbone, so possible you are using underscore too. Bind should help:

```
initialize: function () {
    var foo = function () { this.drawSomething(); };
    foo = _.bind(foo, this);
    setInterval(foo, 1000);
}
```

or jQuery analog Proxy:

```
foo = $.proxy(foo, this);
```

Answer (score 0):

as quick solution

```
initialize: function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        //alert("Hello");
        this.drawSomething();
    }.bind(this), 1000);
},
drawSomething: function() {
    alert('hi');
},
```

but I would prefer to use additional variable as dfsq methioned, because some old browsers doesn't support bind